# Edit/Add ngClass in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive to refactor some classes manipulation.

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Am5H/).

I want to add or edit the ng-class attribute from my track directive to avoid this dupplicated code (in the ng-classes):

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="track in tracks"
      ng-class="{
        'track-is-stopped': trackState === 'stop',
        'track-is-playing track-is-paused': trackState === 'pause',
        'track-is-playing': trackState === 'play',
        'track-is-playing track-is-buffering': trackState === 'buffering'
      }"
      track>
      <td>{{ track.title }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <div ng-class="{ 
       selected: selected,
       'track-is-stopped': trackState === 'stop',
       'track-is-playing track-is-paused': trackState === 'pause',
       'track-is-playing': trackState === 'play',
       'track-is-playing track-is-buffering': trackState === 'buffering'           
     }" 
     ng-repeat="track in tracks"
     track>{{ track.title }} 
</div>
```

I want to control this part in my directive:

```
      ng-class="{
        'track-is-stopped': trackState === 'stop',
        'track-is-playing track-is-paused': trackState === 'pause',
        'track-is-playing': trackState === 'play',
        'track-is-playing track-is-buffering': trackState === 'buffering'
      }"
```

How to do that? 
It has to work with any element and has to work with any existing ng-class attribute (so I need to extend the current attribute):

```
ng-class="{ selected: selected }"
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'how to do that?'. are you having any specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `getClass()` in the directive's controller:

   ```js
   // ...
   controller: function ($scope) {
       $scope.getClass = function () {
           return {
               'track-is-stopped': $scope.trackState === 'stop',
               'track-is-playing track-is-paused': $scope.trackState === 'pause',
               'track-is-playing': $scope.trackState === 'play',
               'track-is-playing track-is-buffering': $scope.trackState === 'buffering'
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call it in the view:

   ```html
   <div ng-class="getClass()">
   ```
3. You can also safely clean the class object from duplicate classes:

   ```js
   // ...
   return {
     'track-is-stopped': $scope.trackState === 'stop',
     'track-is-paused': $scope.trackState === 'pause',
     'track-is-playing': $scope.trackState === 'play',
     'track-is-buffering': $scope.trackState === 'buffering'
   }
   ```